# foreach variable causing "<identifier> expected" error on compile

Tags: java, foreach

I am working on a homework assignment for an Intro to Java class. When I try and compile my code I am getting a compilation error. I am sure it is something simple, but I cannot figure out the cause of the error.

Note, the errors I am receiving are under the source code.

```
/* Logical Design

start
  // Declarations
  final String QUESTIONS[] = new String{"Please input your answer using A, B, or C.\nWho is the coolest guy ever? \n\nA. Max\nB. James Bond\nC. Burt Reynolds", "Please input your answer using A, B, or C.\nWho do coolguys' drive?\n\nA. Datuns\nB. Panters\nC. Porsches", "Please input your answer using A, B, or C.\nWhat is the coolest city?\n\nA. Los Angles\nB. Denver\nC.Boulder"};
  final String CONGRATS = "You got it right!"
  final string FAIL = "Horribly. Horribly wrong. =["
  final String ANSWERS[] = new String{"A","A","A"};
  final String QUIT = "QUIT";
  String tempanswer[] = new String[3]
  int index;
  int index2;
  String keeplaying;


  Output "Would you like to play?"
  input keeplaying
  if(keepplaying == QUIT) {
  return;
  } else {
    for(index = 0; index<QUESTIONS.length; index++) {
    Output QUESTIONS[index]
    input tempanswer[index];
      for(index2 = 0; index2<ANSWERS.length; index2++) {
        if tempanswer == ANSWERS[index2] {
        output CONGRATS } else { output FAIL }
      }
    }
  }
stop
*/

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class FunQuiz
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
  final String QUESTIONS[] = {"Please input your answer using A, B, or C.\nWho is the coolest guy ever? \n\nA. Max\nB. James Bond\nC. Burt Reynolds", "Please input your answer using A, B, or C.\nWhat do coolguys' drive?\n\nA. Datuns\nB. Panters\nC. Porsches", "Please input your answer using A, B, or C.\nWhat is the coolest city?\n\nA. Los Angles\nB. Denver\nC.Boulder"};
  final String ANSWERS[] = {"A","A","A"};
  final String QUIT = "QUIT";
  String tempanswer[] = new String[3];
  int index;
  int index2;
  String keeplaying;

  keepplaying = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to play?");
  if(keepplaying == QUIT) {
  return;
  } else {
    for(index = 0; index<QUESTIONS.length; index++) {
    System.out.println(QUESTIONS[index]);
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(tempanswer[index]);
      for(index2 = 0; index2<ANSWERS.length; index2++) {
        if(tempanswer == ANSWERS[index2]) {
        System.out.println("You got question " . index2 . " correct!");} else { System.out.println("You got question " . index2 . " incorrect.");}
      }
    }
  }

  System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

These are the errors I get on compile

```
FunQuiz.java:57: <identifier> expected
        System.out.println("You got question " . index2 . " correct!");} else { System.out.println("You got question " . index2 . " incorrect.");}
                                                         ^
FunQuiz.java:57: ';' expected
        System.out.println("You got question " . index2 . " correct!");} else { System.out.println("You got question " . index2 . " incorrect.");}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `System.out.println("You got question " + index2 + " correct!");}` instead of

```
System.out.println("You got question " . index2 . " correct!");};
```

Java uses + for concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

In JAVA the concatenation simbol is not "." but "+".
Use `System.out.println("You got question " + index2 + " correct!");}`